# Rolling moving average at different frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a dataset with daily data and am trying to create aggregate statistical summaries based on a 3 calendar month rolling window. So for example, given this dataset:

```
        date  amount
0 2015-01-01     100
1 2015-01-05     500
2 2015-02-12      50
3 2015-03-25      50
4 2015-03-04     100
5 2015-04-19     500
6 2015-05-31      50
7 2015-05-01     100
8 2015-06-09     500
9 2015-07-15      50
```

If I wanted to calculate the kurtosis and standard of `amount`, I would get the following:

```
        date      sd   kurtosis
0 2015-01-01     NaN        NaN    
1 2015-02-01     NaN        NaN
2 2015-03-01     171        4.7
3 2015-04-01     189        3.8
4 2015-05-01     171        4.7
5 2015-06-01     213       -5.8
6 2015-07-01     189        3.8
```

Note that these measures are calculated on the daily values for the current and prior 2 months. Is there a way of solving this using `rolling`?

Comment: Month is not a fix window size, so it's somewhat vague as to what you mean by rolling 3 months.

Comment: @QuangHoang clarified that I mean calendar month.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `min_periods` argument as 1. As it is described on the docs, the default value is the window size.
And it adds `NaN` for entries less or equal this parameter (`min_periods`).

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

For your case, you're rolling on a 3 window size. I don't know how you have coded to group days in months, but for the same time-scale would be like this:

```
df['sd'] = df.rolling(3, min_periods=1).std()
df['kurtosis'] = df.rolling(3, min_periods=1).kurtosis()
```

Answer (score 0):

Employing `rolling()` could be difficult here, as you have to look both ahead and backward in your dataframe to get the desired window.

Here is an approach that uses a mask to get the desired window for each index (i.e., window between the first day of the month two calendar months before current month and the last of the current month) and then applies a function to the `amount` column in that window:

```
df = df.set_index('date')

df["roll_std"] = [
    df[
        (df.index >= (curr + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)))
        & (df.index <= (curr + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - pd.offsets.Day(1)))
    ]["amount"].std(ddof=0)
    for curr in df.index
]

df["roll_krt"] = [
    df[
        (df.index >= (curr + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(3)))
        & (df.index <= (curr + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1) - pd.offsets.Day(1)))
    ]["amount"].kurtosis()
    for curr in df.index
]
```

This will create new columns in the original day-level dataframe.  You can then do the final housekeeping to condense it down to month-level and set the first two months to null, if you need to.

```
df["yr_mon"] = df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(-1) + pd.offsets.Day(1)
monthly_df = (
    df[["yr_mon", "roll_std", "roll_krt"]]
    .drop_duplicates(subset="yr_mon")
    .sort_values(by="yr_mon")
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
monthly_df.loc[:1, ["roll_std", "roll_krt"]] = None
monthly_df
#           yr_mon    roll_std  roll_krt
#  0    2015-01-01         NaN       NaN
#  1    2015-02-01         NaN       NaN
#  2    2015-03-01  171.464282  4.663335
#  3    2015-04-01  188.745861  3.750693
#  4    2015-05-01  171.464282  4.663335
#  5    2015-06-01  213.234026  -5.794877
#  6    2015-07-01  188.745861  3.750693
```